# Unmerge _cell in python using openpyxl module

Tags: python, openpyxl

Why unmerge_cell function in python openpyxl does not work perpectly ?!

```
 import datetime
 import openpyxl
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book2.xlsx')
 for ws in wb:
    for x in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
       print(x)
       ws.unmerge_cells(str(x))
 wb.save('re-book2.xlsx')
```

something wrong but I don't know why. I expect output must be:

```
[<CellRange A2:B3>, <CellRange B4:B5>]

A2:B3

B4:B5
```

But the actual output is:

```
[<CellRange A2:B3>, <CellRange B4:B5>]

 A2:B3
```

P/s: if I delete a below line code then the output be as i expected!.

```
ws.unmerge_cells(str(x))
```

or using:

```
for x in ws.merged_cell_ranges:
```

to replace

```
for x in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
```

then it's work fine. I dont know why. Somebody can explain to me. Sorry for my poor english. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are changeing the `ws.merged_cells.ranges:` while `iterating` over it. Change to `for x in list(ws.merged_cells.ranges):` will work. Beside this, read the [tutorial - merge-unmerge-cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=merge%20cells#merge-unmerge-cells) how it's intended to do and [Deprecated](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=merged_cells#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.merged_cell_ranges)

Answer (score 1):

try this in your code:

```
#######################################
#Iterate through all worksheets in a workbook and unmerge cells

    for sheet in wb:
        ws = wb[sheet]
        print('Now in sheet: ' + ws.title)
        # Remove merged cells
        mergedRanges=ws.merged_cells.ranges
        o=0
        while mergedRanges:
            for entry in mergedRanges:
                o=+1
                print("  unMerging: " + str(o) + ": " +str(entry))
                ws.unmerge_cells(str(entry))

#######################################
```